# html rowspan not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have what should be some pretty easy html, but for some reason, I cannot get a `rowspan` to work. Instead of filling the entire lefthand column, it's only occupying a cell on the bottom part of it. I'd like to get something like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| label 1  | content 1 | label 2 |
|          +-----------+         |
|          | content 2 |         |
|          +-----------+         |
|          | content 3 |         |
|          +-----------+         |
|          | content 4 |         |
|          +-----------+         |
|          | content 5 |         |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

but am having no luck with the below code. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ucozub/1/edit).

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="5">
        label one
    </td>
    <td>
        content 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        content 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        content 3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        content 4
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        content 5
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        label two
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">


    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            label one
        </td>
        <td>
            content 1
        </td>
      <td rowspan="5">
            label two
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr rowspan="5">
        <td>
            content 5
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a small html change:

```
<table border="1">


    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            label one
        </td>
        <td>
            content 1
        </td>
      <td rowspan="5">
            label two
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            content 5
        </td>

    </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the vertical-align:top to an inline style, or set a class and do the same. Should work.

```
<td rowspan="5" style="vertical-align:top">
```

Comment: the vertical alignment is not the issue. Thanks for taking a look though.